# pmount cannot mount removable encrypted usb disk

Tags: debian, mount, encryption, dm-crypt

I am creating a mapper file /dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c on boot in /etc/crypttab like this:

```
luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c UUID=672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c     /home/user1/keyfile_sandisk120gb luks,keyscript=/bin/cat
```

Output of lsblk is this:

```
sdd                                             8:48   1 114,6G  0 disk  
└─luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c   253:2    0 114,6G  0 crypt
```

Then when I run my backup script I use pmount like this:

```
pmount /dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c
```

But I get:

```
Error: device /dev/dm-2 is not removable
```

This normally mounts the ext4 partition to /media/disk_by-partlabel_sandisk120gb.
When the disk (removable USB flash drive) was not encrypted everything worked fine.
But now pmount does not understand that the encrypted disk is on a pen drive.
Maybe I need to add an option to crypttab? I want to use pmount and not mount because pmount does not require root.

I am on debian bullseye.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the name nor version of your Linux distribution, but at least on Debian 11, `pmount` is capable of detecting LUKS and invoking `cryptsetup` automatically, so you should not need an entry in `/etc/crypttab` for it (but then you cannot use a keyfile, which you seem to be doing here).

Before mounting a device, `pmount` will require that either the device to be mounted is removable, or that the device has been specifically whitelisted in `/etc/pmount.allow`. Adding a generic device-mapper device node like `/dev/dm-2` to pmount whitelist is probably not a very good idea, as it might easily refer to some other device after a reboot.

The goal of `pmount` is to allow regular users to use removable media without root access. But in your case, since you have created a `crypttab` entry, root access is already involved. You might make a regular `/etc/fstab` entry with the `user` mount option:

```
/dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c /media/disk_by-partlabel_sandisk120gb ext4 user,rw 0 0
```

If your `/bin/mount` command is setuid root (i.e. is owned by root and has permissions `-r-s--x--x` or greater), the `user` option in `/etc/fstab` should authorize regular users to mount *that specific mountpoint only* by running

```
mount /media/disk_by-partlabel_sandisk120gb
```

and likewise unmount it by

```
umount /media/disk_by-partlabel_sandisk120gb
```

When using `mount` as a non-root user, it is important to specify **only** the mountpoint **or** the device name, not both. This triggers `mount` to use the pre-authorized entry in `/etc/fstab`.

If you specify both the device name and the mountpoint, the command will assume you are doing a fully custom/ad-hoc mount operation, which will always require root access.

Note that unlike `pmount`, `mount` will also require that `/media/disk_by-partlabel_sandisk120gb` exists as an empty directory, so that it can be used as a mount point.

Comment: I cannot use fstab because I don't want to mount the device on boot. I think I will use the /etc/pmount.allow file. Would it also be possible to mark the mapper file as removable media?

Comment: You can still use fstab, just add the `noauto` mount option to prevent auto-mounting the entry at boot. And no, I don't think you can mark the mapper file as removable, as there does not seem to be an option for that in the device-mapper.